# DateEntry en tkinter no funciona

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

tengo un inconveniente con tkinter, el programa no compila y la terminal me arroja:

> AttributeError: 'DateEntry' object has no attribute '_calendar'

No sé que lo está causando, no hay errores en el código y las extensiones están importadas, dejo abajo el código exactamente cómo lo tengo para que puedan reproducirlo.

```
import tkinter as tk
import ttkbootstrap as ttkb
from ttkbootstrap.constants import *
import tkcalendar
from tkcalendar import *
from tkcalendar import DateEntry

ventana_reporte_fechas=tk.Tk()
ventana_reporte_fechas.geometry("700x500")

label_titulo=ttkb.Label(ventana_reporte_fechas, text="Reporte entre fechas", font=("Arial", 16))
label_titulo.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=5, pady=5)

#Linea de fechas
label_elegir_fecha=ttkb.Label(ventana_reporte_fechas, text="Fecha:", font=("Arial", 14))
label_elegir_fecha.grid(column=0, row=1, padx=5, pady=5)

date1 =DateEntry(ventana_reporte_fechas, datepattern="%d/%m/%Y")
date1.grid(column=1, row=1, padx=10,pady=10)

ventana_reporte_fechas.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que el módulo **ttkbootstrap** también tiene una clase con el nombre **DateEntry** y genera conflictos con la clase **DateEntry** en el módulo **tkcalendar**. No es necesario usar el módulo tkcalendar. El código quedaría así:

```
import tkinter as tk
import ttkbootstrap as ttkb
from ttkbootstrap.constants import *

ventana_reporte_fechas=tk.Tk()
ventana_reporte_fechas.geometry("700x500")


label_titulo=ttkb.Label(ventana_reporte_fechas, text="Reporte entre fechas", font=("Arial", 16))
label_titulo.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=5, pady=5)

#Linea de fechas
label_elegir_fecha=ttkb.Label(ventana_reporte_fechas, text="Fecha:", font=("Arial", 14))
label_elegir_fecha.grid(column=0, row=1, padx=5, pady=5)

date1 = ttkb.DateEntry(ventana_reporte_fechas)
date1.grid(column=1, row=1, padx=10,pady=10)

ventana_reporte_fechas.mainloop()
```

Comment: Funcionó perfecto hermano, muchas gracias.